# Sending hex dump of ollydbg through WS2_32.send

Tags: c++, sockets, winapi, hook

I am messing around with dll injection and successfully hooked the send (https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms740149(v=vs.85).aspx) function where a game sends packets to the server.

When I set a breakpoint at this function in ollydbg and follow the buf in the hexdump I recognized that every time I do a specific action the buffer contains "00 00 00 00 00 0C 06 FE".

How can I mimic this action? I already tried sending the hexvalue, but it doesn't work somehow.

```
send(gameSocket, (const char*)0x00000000000C06FE, 8, 0);
```

How ever the send function actually works, since when I send something like "qweqwe" I get disconnected from the server.

Can anybody tell me how I can send this specific hexdump?

EDIT: I found the solution. I was sending the packets to fast, so that the server disconnected me. A simple Sleep(1000) does the job.

Comment: "the buffer contains" or "buffer pointer is" ?  `I send something like "qweqwe" I get disconnected from the server.` may be server not understand what is "qweqwe" and decide not chat with you any more

Comment: Yeah the server disconnects me since it doesn't know the command I guess. I added a picture (wanted to add more, but I am not allowed to) of the hexdump. If I follow the DWORD (0C06FE) in dump it doesn't contain anything